# CAAnimation - Show/Hide with duration of 0

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, core-animation

I'm using `CAAnimation` to animate layers, and then overlay them on a video using `AVExportSession`.

I'm trying to make a layer appear/disappear instantaneously by setting the duration to 0. However, there seems to be a minimum value of `0.25f` and thus, animating properties like opacity have a transition.

Is it possible to achieve an instantaneous show/hide of a `CALayer`using `CAAnimation`?

Comment: Try setting it to a small non-zero value.  If you leave it as 0 it inherits the duration from the transaction it's in.

Comment: although hacky but dan's suggestion is the only way achieving it...

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest you take a quick look at Core Animation Programming Guide here - [Animation_Types_Timing](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Animation_Types_Timing/Articles/Timing.html)

you can also try non-zero value as dan suggested as a quick hack.

I hope that might put you on the right track.

Comment: So @dan method works pretty well. The problem is, if I want the caption to be visible at the beginning of the video (beginTime = AVCoreAnimationBeginTimeAtZero) there is a very quick flash. I can set beginTime to be a negative number, and the export looks fine, but in the player there is still a flash.